# Sublime Text 2 Syntax Highlighting Problems

Tags: php, html, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2

So, I've been using Sublime Text 2 unregistered, and i've installed some plugins.  But, I am having a major problem.

The syntax highlighting for PHP and HTML keeps getting mixed up (and the save as file type and snippets). Originally, everything was fine, then suddenly (maybe after installing a certain plugin?), whenever I switched to PHP syntax highlighting, it actually went to HTML and showed HTML on the bottom right-hand corner.

Later, PHP syntax highlighting worked and the thing in the corner said "PHP", but it saved as .HTML as default. But now, when switching to PHP syntax highlighting, it says "PHP", but it is actually HTML and saves as such. And when switching to HTML, it says "PHP", but it is actually HTML.

Between the last 2 incidents, I installed no new plugins or removed old ones, I don't think.

What is going on? How do I fix it? This has been occurring over the past few days/weeks. I'd consider registering, but I need to be able to work in all languages.

Comment: When I had the syntax at HTML (and it said "PHP") and reopened it, it said "HTML", so I tried to switch it to PHP and reopen it, but it still did not have any syntax highlighting.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling or [reverting to a freshly installed state](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html)?

Comment: This question is clear to me, because I'm having the exact opposite situation:  an HTML file is using PHP syntax by default. When I switch it to HTML in the syntax menu, HTML is checked, but the button right corner still say PHP, and the syntax being used is PHP.

The question is:  does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue with a registered copy of Sublime Text 3

Comment: I find it a bit of a shame when this gets closed before a solution is posted that fixes it. 'As not a real question ?' I disagree.

Comment: Having the same issue ... Here is the question on the sublime text forum - waiting for an answer:
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9510&p=64365#p64365

Comment: Sublime is expecting the `<?php` tag to encompass your php code. Try placing `<?php` up top and `?>` on the bottom of the page and you should be able to then see php-specific text highlighting.